# expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (308, 1, 6)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to use Conv1D for the first time for multiclass classification of time series data and my model keeps throwing this error when I use it.

```
import numpy as np
import os

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Dense, TimeDistributed, MaxPooling1D, Flatten

# fix random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(7)

dataset1 = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join('data', 'norm_cellcycle_384_17.txt'), delimiter=',', dtype=None)
data = dataset1[1:]

# extract columns
genes = data[:,0]
y_all = data[:,1].astype(int)
x_all = data[:,2:-1].astype(float)

# deleted this line when using sparse_categorical_crossentropy
# 384x6
y_all = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_all)

# 5
num_classes = np.unique(y_all).shape[0]

# split entire data into train set and test set
validation_split = 0.2

val_idx = np.random.choice(range(x_all.shape[0]), int(validation_split*x_all.shape[0]), replace=False)
train_idx = [x for x in range(x_all.shape[0]) if x not in val_idx]

x_train = x_all[train_idx]
y_train = y_all[train_idx]

# 308x17x1
x_train = x_train[:, :, np.newaxis]
# 308x1
y_train = y_train[:,np.newaxis]

x_test = x_all[val_idx]
y_test = y_all[val_idx]

# deleted this line when using sparse_categorical_crossentropy
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

# 76x17x1
x_test = x_test[:, :, np.newaxis]
# 76x1
y_test = y_test[:,np.newaxis]


print(x_train.shape[0],'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0],'test samples')


# Create Model 
# number of filters for 1D conv
nb_filter = 4
filter_length = 5

window = x_train.shape[1]
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=nb_filter,kernel_size=filter_length,activation="relu", input_shape=(window,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Conv1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_length, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=2, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

I don't know why I get this error. When I use binary_crossentropy loss and no one hot encoding for y_all, my model works. But it fails when I use one hot encoding for y_all with categorical_crossentropy loss. When I don't use one hot encoding, keras throws an error making me change y_all to one a binary matrix.
I don't even know where the (1,6) are coming from in the array.

> ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (308, 1, 6)

Please help! I've been stuck on this for many hours! Already went through all the related questions but still doesn't make sense.

Update: I now use sparse_categorical_crossentropy because it has integer support. I deleted the to_categorical lines from the above code and I get this new error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Received a label value
>   of 5 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).  Label values: 2 5
>   [[Node:
>   SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
>   = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlabels=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_1, Cast)]]

Requested sample of data:

```
,Main,Gp,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17
YDL179w,1,-0.75808,-0.90319,-0.98935,-0.73995,-0.67193,-0.12777,-0.95307,-1.01656,0.79730,2.11688,1.98537,0.61591,0.56603,-0.13684,-0.52228,-0.05068,0.78823,
YLR079w,1,-0.48845,-0.70828,-0.47688,-0.65814,-0.45374,-0.47302,-0.71214,-1.02839,0.24048,3.11376,1.28952,0.44874,0.04379,-0.31104,-0.30332,-0.34575,0.82285,
YER111c,1,-0.42218,0.23887,1.84427,-0.02083,-0.61105,-0.65827,-0.79992,-0.39857,-0.09166,2.03314,1.58457,0.68744,0.14443,-0.72910,-1.46097,-0.82353,-0.51662,
YBR200w,1,0.09824,0.55258,-0.89641,-1.19111,-1.11744,-0.76133,0.09824,2.16120,1.46126,1.03148,0.67537,-0.33155,-0.60170,-1.39987,-0.42978,-0.15963,0.81045,
YPL209c,2,-0.65282,-0.32055,2.53702,2.00538,0.60982,0.51014,-0.55314,-1.01832,-0.78573,0.01173,0.07818,-0.05473,-0.22087,0.24432,-0.28732,-1.11801,-0.98510,
YJL074c,2,-0.81087,-0.19448,1.72941,0.59002,-0.53069,-0.25051,-0.92294,-0.92294,-0.53069,0.08570,1.87884,1.97223,0.45927,-0.36258,-0.34390,-1.07237,-0.77351,
YNL233w,2,-0.43997,0.66325,2.85098,0.74739,-0.42127,-0.47736,-0.79524,-0.80459,-0.48671,-0.21558,1.25226,1.01852,-0.10339,-0.56151,-0.96353,-0.46801,-0.79524,
YLR313c,2,-0.46611,0.42952,3.01689,1.13856,0.01902,-0.44123,-0.66514,-0.98856,-0.59050,-0.47855,0.84002,0.39220,0.50416,-0.50342,-0.82685,-0.64026,-0.73977,
YGR041w,2,-0.57187,-0.26687,1.10561,-0.38125,-0.68624,-0.26687,-0.87687,-1.18186,-0.80062,0.60999,2.09686,1.82998,1.14374,0.11437,-0.80062,-0.87687,-0.19062,
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your data

Comment: @Pedia added some rows from my data!

Answer (score 1):

So I noticed that even though I know there are 5 classes in this dataset as seen by the unique values obtained for y_all, for some reason Keras to_categorical thinks there are 6 classes.

```
# 384x6 
y_all = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_all)

# 5 
num_classes = np.unique(y_all).shape[0]
```

I don't know why that is. Keeping this in mind I changed this line of code and my model began to run:

> model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

to

> model.add(Dense(num_classes+1, activation='softmax'))

I still don't know why to_categorical behaves this way. Anyone know?

Comment: i think it's just looking at the maximum integer value and assuming that you have classes from 0 up to that number

Comment: the 0 indexing assumption doesn't make sense. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

`to_categorical(x)` in Keras will encode the given parameter into `n` number of classes where `n = max(x) + 1`, i.e. generally speaking from `[0 , max(x)]`.